# What is this line doing? arr.length >>> 0

Tags: javascript, operators

What is this for:

```
arr.length >>> 0
```

And why should I want to use it?

Comment: also I need help on the tags to add the name of that operator, since I don't know its name

Comment: Context is king... give us some.

Comment: I normally don't like to edit code in questions, but I'm *fairly* sure you meant `length`, not `lenght`.

Comment: That is a "bitwise operator".  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: You need to include more detail in your question. Where did you find that line of code? Is there a specific task that you need help with? Have you looked at php's documentation for the answer?

Comment: There is never a case in javascript where an array's length can be anything other than a non-negative integer. Coercing an integer to an integer is utterly pointless.

Comment: @itsmequinn: ehem: javascript, not php here.  A lot of useful parallels here except that '>>>' is undocumented in PHP (http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).  Different subject matter.

Comment: @RobG that is was I was looking for. It is a very neat operator that I am surely will be using, but never for this useless purpose. +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the unsigned right shift operator. In this case (when used with `0`) it ensures that `arr.length` is an integer, or rather, evaluates to `arr.length` as strict unsigned 32-bit integer value. (This means it's never `NaN`, never negative, and never has a decimal part.)

Examples:

```
'1'       >>> 0: 1
1         >>> 0: 1
''        >>> 0: 0
undefined >>> 0: 0
null      >>> 0: 0
1.0∙∙∙01  >>> 0: 1
```

Compare to:

```
Number('1')      : 1
Number(1)        : 1
Number('')       : 0
Number(undefined): NaN
Number(null)     : 0
Number(1.0∙∙∙01) : 1.0∙∙∙01
```

It’s just there to ensure that the right length is being used.

Answer (score 4):

Ensures that `.length` is a 32-bit integer.

In most implementations, Array indices are limited to a 32-bit range *(at least when working with `Array.prototype` methods, and the magic behaviors of `.length`)*.

Comment: You missed `…why should I want to use it?`. The only case where it might be considered is if *length* might be set to a non-integer value. But that [can't occur](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.5.1) in an implementation conforming to ECMA-262. Length is **always** a non-negative integer. So the answer is: **never**.

Comment: I wouldn't say "never". It's used if you're writing a shim for a standard `Array.prototype` method that endeavors to be ECMA-262 compliant (or as close as possible), since the standard methods do a *`ToUint32(lenVal)`* conversion. Also the spec allows `Array.prototype` methods to be applied to "array-like" objects. This would provide the motivation for a shim to enforce the proper `.length` value.

Comment: If that were the case, then -ve values need to be dealt with first as `>>>` has some drastic effects on those. And it limits the size of length to quite a bit less than that available for built-in *array.length*, so it's a poor method for ensuring or converting the value to a non-negative integer.

Comment: @RobG: *"it limits the size of length to quite a bit less..."* It places the same limitation that the standard methods do. Note that you wouldn't overwrite the `.length`. You'd do something more like `var len = this.length >>> 0`.

Comment: So you'd be happy with `-9 >>> 0 => 4294967287` and `4.9e9 >>> 0 => 605032704`? Dealing with -ve values depends on the context (perhaps they should be zero), but 4.9e9 should be 490000000. Bit-shifting runs the risk of pushing bits off the end, an alternative is something like `Math.abs(Math.floor(v))`, though I admit I use `x | 0` for truncation where the values are reasonably small

Comment: @RobG: Well, that would be the same behavior you'd get if you have such a length value on an Array-like object, and apply the standard `Array.prototype` methods to it. Like... `var obj = {length:4.9e9}; Array.prototype.forEach.call(obj, func...)`. The last index it processes will be the value of `(4.9e9 >>> 0) - 1`

Comment: @RobG: re: ECMA-262.  Which browsers have not followed this standard either now or in the past?  Answering that should anser OP's question of "why should I want to use it".  In regards to your "So you'd be happy with -9 >>> 0 => 4294967287" comment, no, OP needs more checks then.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer—there are various quirks, mostly minor, such as IE thinking a single trailing comma in an array literal is an elision (it isn't), issues with named function expressions and so on. Yes, context is king. Without knowing what the operation is trying achieve it's hard to say whether potential issues are valid or not.